# How to connect MetaMask with Web3.js version 1.2.6?

Tags: node.js, express, web3js, metamask

I have written a smart contract (deployed on Ropsten) and a website (node.js, express.js and ejs)

I can read data from the contract with Infura API and shown on the web page successfully. However, I want to write data on the contract through Metamask.
Currently. I cannot connect MetaMask with web3.js 1.2.6. I have checked Web3.givenProvider return null also.

(I can interactive with my smart contract through MyEtherWallet + Meta Mask)

Detail information:

Development envrionment: node.js express.js ejs web3.js(1.2.6)

Browser: chrome + MetaMask: localhost:3000 / 127.0.0.1:3000

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Web3 = require('web3');
//const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxx"));
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);

const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

let myAddress = '0x3E0980E7cea6804B01BEA49cb70F9B7Cxxxxxxxx';
const abi = [***VERY LONG ABI***];
const address = "0x07cf2ecef130495ea18a25e4f1dfbfc4xxxxxxxx";
const MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

// define the home page route
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const resultHome = [];

    MyContract.methods.name().call().then((name) => {
        resultHome.push(name);
        symbol();
    })
    const symbol = () => {
        MyContract.methods.symbol().call().then((symbol) => {
            resultHome.push(symbol);
            totalSupply();
        })
    }
    const totalSupply = () => {
        MyContract.methods.totalSupply().call().then((totalSupply) => {
            resultHome.push(totalSupply);
            home();
        })
    }

    const home = () => {
        res.render('erc20/index', {
            pageTitle: 'ERC-20E Token Standard Enhanced - Info',
            path: 'erc20',
            subPath: 'erc20Info',
            name: resultHome[0],
            symbol: resultHome[1],
            address: address,
            totalSupply: resultHome[2] / 100
        })
    }
})

router.get('/source', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/erc20Source.txt');
})

// define the controller route
router.get('/controller', (req, res, next) => {
    let resultController = [];

    MyContract.methods.showRun().call().then((showRun) => {
        resultController.push(showRun);
        controller();
    })

    const controller = () => {
        res.render('erc20/controller', {
            pageTitle: 'ERC-20E Token Standard Enhanced - Controller',
            path: 'erc20',
            subPath: 'erc20Controller',
            showRun: resultController[0]
        })
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem have solved since I put the web3 at the front end instead of the back end.